# Any way to generate documentation of a website project in a restricted environment?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, documentation, restriction, limited-user

Following the title, I have am unable to execute cmdlets, exe, shellscripts, vb. All that I am able open is git bash, but again, I have no admin rights. Are there any ways of accomplishing this? 1 idea i had was to create a local website that does this for us in the form where we upload a zip file to the website then it does its stuff then repacks it and sends it back to us via a local zip file download?

EDIT:
I am trying to document out a front end site coded in react. Only thing that is able to run anything within itself is Git Bash. No execution of .exe's or cmdlets withing Git Bash works though...

Comment: You're going to need to provide more details. What is the process you are using to generate documentation, and what is the source data that you are building the documentation from?

Answer (score 0):

Well, apparently if u have git bash in ur restricted laptop and have the ability to push ur commit to git hub, it seems that using EDoc node module does the job.

Instead of saving globally (which won't work) do a npm install -save esdoc.
Then instead of running esdoc -c [json file], use ./node_modules/esdoc/out/src/esdoccli.js -c [json file]

Worked beautifully for me. Hope this helps anyone who faces a similar situation as me. Feel free to add additional methods to generate documentation.